# Headless Drupal creating content via RESTful services

Tags: angularjs, rest, drupal-7

I'm very new to AngularJS and I have the task of using it to create a Headless Drupal interface.

I've hit a problem where I encounter the following error:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.<br />
The number of request header fields exceeds this server's limit.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at 127.0.0.1 Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

Here's the code I'm using:

```
//test function
$scope.test = function() {
  console.log("NODE Test function responding!");
  var user_session = $cookieStore.get('user_session');
  console.log(user_session);

  var nodeObj = {
    "title": "Node Test",
    "body": "Node body contents test#2",
    "type": "page"
  };
  var nodeObj = {
    "type": "page",
    "title": "New Page",
    "language": "und"
  };

  var res = $http.post("http://mydrupal-services-site/angularjs-headless/api/v1/node", nodeObj, {
    "headers": user_session
  });
  res.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.message = data;
    console.log("Success: ");
    console.log(data);
  });
  res.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    console.error(data);
  });
}
```

After searching, I found a post which suggested adding `LimitRequestFieldSize 16384` to my VirtualHost would solve the problem but it did not.

**UPDATE**

My *user_session* variable contains the following (which is only 144 characters long):

```
Cookie:SESSb22b2ff3837c37411e0b1da3fbd77b0c=_bwpgljhXPwcA_ZfmZpL2IrnIvo25PX_APYdzrIcM08 X-CSRF-Token:GwXcAwctxVcOi_FvI-Mfm6HYQaLoWAFnvkQQ-Nnzbhs
```

Comment: Please check my answer, just a question to you: why is your user_session cookie longer than 6028 chars?!

Comment: Hi @lin, my user_session data is only 144 characters long. I included it as an update  to the question

Comment: Could you add the full request headers send by your HTTP-Request? (raw output of network tab in console)

Comment: Any update on this?

Answer (score 0):

> The number of request header fields exceeds this server's limit.

Your are allowed to send max 8KB in a header by default (apache2). In that way `{"headers": user_session}` is much to long to send in a header. Try to append it on your node object or cut your user session string to max 8KB (6.028 Chars). Btw. you define your `nodeObj` two times in a row. The problem is not related to drupal.

```
$scope.test = function() {
  var nodeObj = {
    "title": "Node Test",
    "body": "Node body contents test#2",
    "type": "page",
    "userSession": $cookieStore.get('user_session')
  };

  $http.post(
   "http://mydrupal-services-site/angularjs-headless/api/v1/node", 
    nodeObj
  ).then(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.message = data;
    console.log("Success:");
    console.log(data);
  }).then(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    console.error(data);
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you feedback. I tested the length of my cookie and it's no longer than 144 character. I also tried your code suggestion but it didn't work for me

Comment: @sisko Could you add the full request headers send by your HTTP-Request? (raw output of network tab in console)